# jquery page load, page keeps getting stuck till the page is fully loaded, instead of displaying the loading gif

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to display the loading gif until the page gets loaded. I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I'm very new to this.

Here is the code:

```
    $("#hm").click(function(){

$("#response").empty().html('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" />');
$("#response").load("file.php");
$("#response").hide();
$("#response").fadeIn("slow");

});
```

try going to link, like url or my images, the loading gif do get displayed but then gets stuck for a while before the page gets loaded..

thanks, Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your code is getting stuck here:

```
url: $('form-demo').action,
```

with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null
```

Comment: to test this i have removed the file which calls for that id, and still it gets stuck, idea ?

Comment: @amin, im not sure what ur page is 'supposed' to do

Comment: as u can see now when u click on tab, lets say the url or my images, it kaind of get stuck, i want stop that from happening ,

Comment: i found the problem, its getting stuck cause i have jquery library to load in every page, since the file is big and its in the header its take time for it load, but the thing is when i remove the jquery library from those files and only leave it in the main file, the fuctions i have on the load pages dont work,

Comment: jquery isnt that big, esp if u use it from CDN

Comment: @Neal try the site now, i have removed the jquery library from loadpages, now its not getting stuck, so wat do u think is causing this if not that.. http://76.73.108.29/#